# How to convert table data to array by using selenium+Javascript

Tags: javascript, selenium

I want to get HTML table data to cover to array by using selenium and Javascript.
I test below code and I can get console.log(lm) in the for loop, but it shows
array each loop.

the wepage is https://www.scoresandodds.com/mlb
and click Game Details-->Line Movement

How I can get array(lm) at the end of the code? why I can not get any
data in my code ?

```
    console.log("Line Movement=================================\n");
driver.findElement(By.xpath('//*[@id="line-movements-tab--65040"]/span')).click(); //Line Movement
await driver.sleep(2500);

let rowC = '';
driver.findElements(By.xpath('//*[@id="line-movements--65040"]/div/table/tbody/tr')).then( function(rows){
        console.log("[" + rows.length + "]" + "\n\n");
        rowC = rows.length;
});

var lm=[];
for (i=0; i<rowC; i++) {
            for (s=1; s<5; s++) {
                var addCellText=function(elem, doneCallback){
                             elem.getText().then(function(textValue){
                                     driver.sleep(1000);
                                     lm.push(textValue);
                                     return doneCallback(null);
                             });
                 };
                 xpath='//*[@id="line-movements--65040"]/div/table/tbody/tr[' + i + ']/td[' + s + ']';
                 driver.findElements(By.xpath(xpath)).then(function(elem){
                       async.each(elem, addCellText, function(error){
                                     driver.sleep(1000);
                                    //console.log(lm);
                       });
                   });
           }
}
console.log("lm");
console.log(lm);
```

each team has a different code such as 65040, please look at each games code in the html. For example today(5/30) ARI-ATL of the code is 65051.

Comment: Where's this element in you page? `//*[@id="line-movements-tab--65040"]/span` I can't find it.

Comment: I can see divs with attribute `data-tab="#line-movements-tab--65040"` followed by a span, but the div with `id="ine-movements-tab--65040"` is followed by another div with class `.frozen`